# How do I add the object in a json url?

Tags: android, json

I am doing a program that involves json and I wanted to ask how do I update the json URL if a new object has been added for example I have an object of foods named apple, banana, and orange in the URL. How do I add strawberries in the URL? This is my JSON URL [MyJSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/6rso2) How do I add an object in foodname for example chicken? Anyone help, please? This is my code so far I can only access it but not able to update it.

```
class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String un;
    private String ea;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //displays the loading window for when connecting to the server
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Food.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait.");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    //this is the doInBackground method, this is where we retrieve and parse data from the aforementioned JSON URL
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //connects to the JSON URL found inside the execute method here => new JSONParser().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/809o6");
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //if status = 200 it means that it successfully established a connection with the JSON URL
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                //gets all the JSON data (JSON objects and arrays) found inside the JSON URL
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONObject rootObj = root.getJSONObject("justincorilla@yahoo.com");
                JSONArray array = rootObj.getJSONArray("foods");
                for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++){

                    JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    FoodInformation food = new FoodInformation();
                    food.setFoodName(obj.getString("foodName"));
                    food.setExpiryDate(obj.getString("expiryDate"));

                    //adds a all the parsed JSON data to the Array List "foodList"
                    foodList.add(food);
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I might be able to help. Please provide some codes, like where you're doing network calls.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? Because you do not want to add new name to any `URL`. You have a `JSON` payload which is a `string` and you need to update it, right? What have you tried? What libraries do you use?

Comment: @DevMike01Can you help me please?